# How to PLAY/STOP mediaplayer again?

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I'm using a button "music" with 2 actions PLAY and STOP , when I click for the first time the music is played , then when I click again it's stopped. However when I click for the second time all actions PLAY/ STOP don't work .

```
   public class Home extends Activity {
      boolean isMediaOn=false; 
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


      final ImageButton music=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.music);
      final MediaPlayer sound=MediaPlayer.create(Accueil.this,R.raw.star);      

      music.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
      public void onClick(View v) { 

                        //  play
              if(isMediaOn==false) 
              { 

              System.out.println("PLAY");

              sound.start();

              music.setImageResource(R.drawable.music);

              isMediaOn=true; 
              } 
                       // stop 
              else 
              { 

                System.out.println("STOP");
                if(sound.isPlaying()){
                    sound.reset();
                    sound.stop();

                }

              music.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_music);

              isMediaOn=false; 
              } 

      } 
      });
```

Here is a screenshot of my logcat : 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're only allowed to call `stop()` when the player is in state `STARTED`, `PREPARED`, `PAUSED` or `PLAYBACK_COMPLETE`. Your `reset()` call is putting it back into `IDLE` state, causing `stop()` to fail.

Comment: @Angelika: Depends on what you're trying to accomplish. For example, why are you calling `reset()`? See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html for info on which states you can reach depending on the current state. In your case you could probably replace your `reset`+`stop` with a `pause` (possibly followed by `seekTo(0)`, depending on the behaviour you're looking for).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use pause(), as in `sound.pause();`

The pause() method pauses playback and maintains all other player states (such as file that's being played, location in file, etc).

Comment: Actually I don't want to use "pause" action , just enable/disable the sound in an application

Comment: Why don't you not want to use pause?

Answer (score 0):

In http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#stop it is clearly stated that 
**'Once in the Stopped state, playback cannot be started until prepare() or prepareAsync() are called to set the MediaPlayer object to the Prepared state again.'**

```
public class Home extends Activity {
  boolean isMediaOn=false; 
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);


  final ImageButton music=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.music);
  final MediaPlayer sound=MediaPlayer.create(Accueil.this,R.raw.star);      

  music.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
  public void onClick(View v) { 

                    //  play
          if(isMediaOn==false) 
          { 

            System.out.println("PLAY");
            try {
               sound.prepare();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(Settings.debug, e.toString());
          }
          sound.start();

          music.setImageResource(R.drawable.music);

          isMediaOn=true; 
          } 
                   // stop 
          else 
          { 

            System.out.println("STOP");
            if(sound.isPlaying()){
                sound.reset();
                sound.stop();

            }

          music.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_music);

          isMediaOn=false; 
          } 

  } 
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, hope this helps you.

```
   final ImageButton music=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.music);
   final MediaPlayer sound=MediaPlayer.create(Accueil.this,R.raw.star);
   music.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

   public void onClick(View v) { 
       if(sound.isPlaying()){
          sound.stop();
          music.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_music);

       } else {
         sound.start();
         music.setImageResource(R.drawable.music);

       }
  });
```